Best way to get a list of file in PHP to be used by devExtreme dxFileManager
I need to read a folder using PHP and create a JSON object with a structure like this in return. I would like to search recursively and maybe using multiple patterns, for example return all test.pdf and test2.xlsx


    var fileSystem = [
    {
        name: "MyFile.jpg",
        size: 1024,
        dateModified: "2019/05/08",
        thumbnail: "/thumbnails/images/jpeg.ico",
        isDirectory: true,
        items: [
            // ...
            // Nested data objects with the same structure
            // ...
        ]
    },
    // ...
    ];



I tried something like this, but I'm not sure how to keep the original structure as this will just use one level. What can I try next?
function rsearch($folder, $pattern_array) {
    $return = array();
    $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator) as $file){
        
        if ($file->isFile()){
            
            $return[] = array(
          'isDirectory'  => false,
          'name'         => $file->getFilename(),
          'size'         => $file->getSize(),
          'dateModified' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $file->getMTime())        
        );
            
        } else {
            
            
            
        }
  
    }
    return $return;
    }


The solution in this comment should help. Can you give it a try?

This works:
function readDirectory($path, $allowedExtensions = []) {
    $result = [];
    $files = scandir($path);

    foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file === '.' || $file === '..') {
      continue;
    }

    $filePath = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
    $fileInfo = pathinfo($filePath);

    if (is_dir($filePath)) {
      $result[] = [
        'name' => $file,
        'isDirectory' => true,
        'items' => readDirectory($filePath, $allowedExtensions)
      ];
    } else {
      if (empty($allowedExtensions) || in_array($fileInfo['extension'], $allowedExtensions)) {
        $result[] = [
          'name' => $file,
          'size' => filesize($filePath),
          'dateModified' => date('Y/m/d', filemtime($filePath)),
          //'thumbnail' => '/thumbnails/images/' . $fileInfo['extension'] . '.ico',
          'isDirectory' => false
        ];
      }
    }
    }

    return $result;
}

